# how to create xml page

Tags: 2011, templating, xml

I am trying to create a page with .xml extension. Below are the steps I followed:

- Created a schema with one text field.
- Created a component with above schema and added desired xml content    to component field.
- Created a DWT and CT for component.
- Created a page DWT to render component presentations.
- Created a PT with extension as ".xml".
- Created a page with above PT and added the above component.

Tried to publish the page.Publish is successful but when i try to view the page, i get an error as below.While page preview works fine.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to see what is really publishing in the final page published? Sounds like strange characters inside the xml file.

Comment: The page that got published contains the xml int below format &lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?&gt;

Comment: I guess you are replying to a comment. If so, could you please move it comments OR update the question adding it.

Comment: I moved your answer and its comments to a comment in your original question. Stack Exchange sites are different from typical forums. We have one question to start a post and multiple answers for that questions. Follow up info should be added to your original question or in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the component content is inside an xml itself, the text is going to be "escaped", so you need something to unescape the content. So the xml is going to be published full of  "& lt;" and "& gt;" characters.

What we usually use is a C# Fragment to unscape such characters. Something like this:

```
Item salida = package.GetByName(Package.OutputName);

string strSalida = salida.GetAsString();
strSalida = strSalida.Replace("&lt;","<");
strSalida = strSalida.Replace("&gt;",">");

package.Remove(salida);
salida.SetAsString(strSalida);
package.PushItem("Output", salida);
```

And Add this C# Fragment after the Dreamweaver Template in the Page Template, as the last stage of the publishing.